# How can I retrieve the difference between two Date instances in minutes?

Tags: java, datetime, talend

According to [the Talend docs](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforDataIntegrationUserGuide520EN/12.5+TalendDate+Routines), it is possible to calculate the difference between two dates using `TalendDate.dateDiffFloor` up to seconds and milliseconds.

However, the docs don't say how (or which format parameter has to be specified).

I have to get this value in seconds as it will feed into a `tInfiniteLoop` component.

I have tried with `"mmmm"` and "`mm`" with no luck. In that case I get the error:

```
Exception in component tMap_3
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't support the dateType: mm ,please try "yyyy" or "MM"
    at routines.TalendDate.diffDateFloor(TalendDate.java:661)
    at timeouttester.job_2_0_1.job_2.tInfiniteLoop_2Process(job_2.java:1156)
    at timeouttester.job_2_0_1.job_2.runJobInTOS(job_2.java:1616)
    at timeouttester.job_2_0_1.job_2.main(job_2.java:1464)
```

Which argument do I have to specify to get minutes? And, if not doable, maybe there is a workaround doing this in "vanilla" Java if not possible via Talend?

I am currently using the following statement in a `tMap` component:

```
TalendDate.diffDateFloor(TalendDate.parseDateInUTC("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Var.expires), TalendDate.getCurrentDate(), "mmmm")
```

Comment: Please post your code so that we could help.

Comment: As it's a Talend job, there is not much code... I'll edit in what I have so far.

Comment: You can parse the two dates using the Java 8 API and it has a method to give you an interval in minutes.

Comment: did you tried "MM"..its different then "mm"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no clue about `Talend` but as you said `vanilla` is also possible for you: You may use the class `Duration` which represents the `duration` between two objects of type `Temporal`. Such a temporal class would, for example, be `Instant` which is a snapshot on the time line. `Instant` has great support in the API. You can retrieve one from `Date#toInstant`, or from `Calendar#toInstant` and more.

See this small example:

```
Date dateBefore = new GregorianCalendar(2014, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 11).getTime();

Instant before = dateBefore.toInstant();
Instant now = Instant.now();

Duration duration = Duration.between(before, now);
System.out.println("Days: " + duration.toDays());
```

However, If I'm not mistaken the class `Instant` itself is only precise down to milliseconds. If that is not enough, you may use another class which implements `Temporal` or create your own.

For your application, you are probably interested in:

```
Duration#toMinutes()
Duration#toMillis()
```

Note that the returned value (`long`) of those methods are rounded downwards (`floor`). So if the *real* amount of minutes where something like `1.453`, `toMinutes()` will return `1` and `toMillis()` returns `1453`.

Comment: Hmm... in Talend I have (by default) only one statement. I might be able to drop in a custom Java component though. if there's no one-statement solution.

Comment: Had to use a custom Java component. But this works. For posterity: Add a `tJavaFlex` component and use the above code to calculate the time different which can then be injected into the flow.